# Why am I seeing artifacts in my simple Vulkan depth demo?

Tags: c++, vulkan

I am making a simple Vulkan depth demo. And there is some artifact in the final result.
I draw two panels both in z-panel.They use the same pipeline but different color and depth compare op.First Panel is blue and depth compare op always and second panel is green and depth compare op equal. The clear value of depth is 0. Both panels are rotating at the z-axis.

Vertex shader

```
#version 450
layout(binding = 0) uniform UniformBufferObject {
    mat4 model;
    mat4 view;
    mat4 proj;
} ubo;

layout(location = 0) in vec2 inPosition;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 inColor;
layout(location = 0) out vec3 fragColor;
layout(push_constant) uniform PushConsts {
    mat4 Rotate;
    vec4 Color;
} pushConsts;

void main() {
    gl_Position = ubo.proj * ubo.view * pushConsts.Rotate * vec4(inPosition, 0.0, 1.0);
    gl_Position.z=gl_Position.w; //this should make depth always 1.0
    fragColor = inColor;
}
```

Fragment Shader

```
#version 450

layout(location = 0) in vec3 fragColor;

layout(location = 0) out vec4 outColor;

layout(push_constant) uniform PushConsts {
    mat4 Rotate;
    vec4 Color;
} pushConsts;

void main() {
    //gl_FragDepth=gl_FragCoord.z/gl_FragCoord.w; this can fix problem
    outColor = vec4(pushConsts.Color.xyz, 1.0);
}
```

Final result:

[image: Final Result]

set gl_FragDepth=1.0 artifact will disapper. And turn the second panel to depth compare op always. The full panel will show so I think no clip during rasterization.
I know about z-fighting. And my major confusion is why 'gl_Position.z=gl_Position.w' is not equal 'gl_fragDepth=1'

Comment: It looks like the kind of artifact that you get when two planes are too close together for your depth buffer (floating point precission). Try moving your green plane up a bit, or increase the number of bits for your depth buffer.